# Can I check if notifications are on for an app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

In Android and iOS system settings you can toggle notifications on an off for an app after granting permissions.

When I go into Android settings, and turn off notifications for my app, the following code (using flutter_local_notifications) still indicates the app has notification permissions.

```
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
```

Is there a way to check if the notifications have been turned on or off for an app?

Answer (score 2):

Are you try use  [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package

```
PermissionStatus? statusNotification = Permission.notification.request();

bool isGranted = statusNotification == PermissionStatus.granted
```

Comment: This methos is not working for me. Can you suggest any other thing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (await  Permission.notification.request().isGranted) {
   //notifications permission is granted do some stuff
}
```